# "let { a, b }: { a: string, b: number } = o" in typeScript

Tags: typescript, syntax

I'm new to TypeScript.  Let's say we have an object called `o` as below:

```
let o = {
    a: "foo",
    b: 12,
    c: "bar"
};
```

Then, `let { a, b } = o;`.
As far as I know, `let { a, b } = o;` means  `var a = o.a, b = o.b;` in **JS**.  I understand this syntax.

But, I miss the point when it comes to `let { a, b }: { a: string, b: number } = o;`.

The example from here: [the example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html)

please explain what's the purpose of  `{ a: string, b: number }`. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax your referring to explicitly declares the local variables `a` and `b` as `string` and `number` respectively, it would be equivalent to:

```
let a: string = o.a;
let b: number = o.b;
```

In this simple coded case, the types could easily be inferred from the object, but you might have a different type you want to assign or return value from an API where you need to spell out what the expected types of the properties are.

A more applicable real-world example where you're consuming an API might look something like:

```
interface MyAPIResponse {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

httpService.get('endpoint').then(({a, b}: MyAPIResponse) => {
   // 'a' will have type string, and 'b' will have type number
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that was a feature when after destructuring the compiler can not detect the types of `a` and `b`. So why this was done to explicitly give the types of the variables. But now without `{ a: string, b: number }` compiler can detect the types.